# Dell Precision M6400 laptop touchpad not responsive to taps after replacing keyboard

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision M6400, running Windows 7. Today I replaced the keyboard with a new OEM keyboard from a top-rated eBay seller. The keyboard works fine, but now the touchpad is not responsive to taps.

The touchpad does move the mouse around, and buttons light up when it passes over them. But tapping the touchpad does not click the buttons.

I tried removing the keyboard and booting up without it. By using the middle button below the touchpad as an Enter key, I was able to get to the Windows logon screen. There, tapping the touchpad worked fine to select which user to log on, and going back to choose a different user.

But when I put the keyboard back on and rebooted, once again the touchpad is not responsive to taps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure all the cables were properly connected?

Comment: @Ramhound The keyboard doesn't have a cable; it seats into a socket. They only cable removed getting to the keyboard is to the LED cover, and yes I made sure that was reconnected correctly.